# Why doesn't my code convert 'char*' to 'const wchar_t*'?

Tags: c++, winapi

From my main.cpp I call this:

```
uintptr_t moduleBase = GetModuleBaseAddress(pid, L"Game.exe");
```

To this function:

```
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}
```

I am aware that GetModuleBaseAddress expects const wchar_t*, but that's why I put the L before "Game.exe"

I don't understand then why I still get this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'const wchar_t*'
```

Comment: Do you have `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` set in project settings? Otherwise you could be getting `modEntry.szModule` as `char`

Comment: please show a [mre] and the full text of the error message

Comment: And hunch confirmed [This is a `UNICODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-moduleentry32w) issue. Define `UNICODE` and this will be fixed

Comment: ^ that or use `MODULEENTRY32W`. And learn to read error messages properly (the LINE NUMBER of the error is critically important)

Comment: What compiler do you use? What is the **verbatim** error message and to which exact line does it refer?

Comment: I used gcc, and this is the line that it refers to: if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))             it underlined modEntry.szModule as red

Comment: `GetModuleBaseAddress` is written to use the `W` versions of the WinAPI so explicitly use the `W` versions of the API, like `Module32FirstW`, and the types needed, like `MODULEENTRY32W`.

Comment: @swiftuseui next time please [edit] and put all relevant information into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed by explicitly using the `W` versions of the API, like the functions [`Module32FirstW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-module32firstw) and [`Module32NextW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-module32nextw) and also the types needed, like [`MODULEENTRY32W`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-moduleentry32w).